# In SQL when we join tables, is there a name for the new table?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

E.g. in Pandas, we can apply a mask and create a new dataframe and assign it a name. Similarly in SQL, once I do a LEFT JOIN of 2 tables, is there a way to refer to the new combined table ?

Comment: You can create a view out of a query  and expose it to the desired users. In mysql views are updatable too. Refer https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-updatability.html

Comment: That would be a "table expression". It could be an *on-the-fly* table expression with an alias; if you want to make it permanent, then you can create a "view" for it.

Comment: @TheImpaler I see, the point of my question is that once I have combined two tables, how do I refer to the new table to do additional analysis in multiple queries. I thought the new table can be assigned to a variable, and future operations done using the variable. Will look into on-the-fly table expression.

Comment: Since you want to use this result in multiple queries afterwards then you probably want to create a view. Then you can compose more queries using this view, plus other tables, or more views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join two table and can get the result in the new combined and also you can give name to that table . Just try this query and if get any doubt just feel free to ask anytime.

```
 MYSQL QUERY
  EMP(C1, C2, CD1)
  DEPT(D1, D2)

  SELECT NEWTABLE.First, NEWTABLE.Third 
  FROM
  (SELECT E.C1 AS First, E.C2 AS Second, D.D2 AS Third FROM EMP E, DEPT D WHERE
   E.CD1 = D.D1) NEWTABLE
   WHERE NEWTABLE.Second > 20;
```

We have created a virtual table i.e *"NEWTABLE"* you can give your name also .

```
(SELECT E.C1 AS First, E.C2 AS Second, D.D2 AS Third FROM EMP E, DEPT D WHERE
       E.CD1 = D.D1)
```

This is the query for where we have applied join query  and also we have selected the three row from two table and renamed it as *"FIRST", "SECOND" and "THIRD"*.

And you will get the doubt in the first line so let me clear we have performed the operation *NEWTABLE.Second > 20*;on the new table which we obtained after join.

If you still get any doubt regarding the query just ask .

Values Stored in the new table is temporary and you can use it for that query only.

And if you want to store permanent value then you have create to new table then assigned that table with the table we joined and so on .

Answer (score 0):

No that won't work in sql, at least not directly

But you can do a subquery

Like

```
SELECT aa.*
FROM
(SELECT t1.*,t2.* FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.refid) aa
```

or A view

```
CREATE VIEW v AS SELECT t1.*,t2.* FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.refid;
```

A problem can result, when you have in both tables the **same names** for columns, that would cause problems, so you must check and in case of equal columnames alias the second column